# Deciding between different PhD programs

Tags: soft-question, advice-request, career

**Edited Version**

- What are the main characteristics and qualities that *you* would consider if you were going to choose a PhD program in theoretical computer science (or related areas) today (based on your experience) and why would you consider them important?
- What are the credible sources that I can get information about those characteristics of PhD programs?

---

Especially I would like to hear your opinion about the following two issues:

- If you had to choose between a program with a global and better brand name and another one with a strong research focus, which one would you choose? why?
- Which of the following two is more important in your opinion: availability of specialization one wants vs general teaching/research quality of faculty?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is too broad.  Voted to close as not a real question.

Comment: Tsuyoshi is correct. StackOverflow type sites work much better with narrow questions. If you ask any of your bullet points as its own question (even the first one; I've been persuaded that's OK), you will be likely to get some good answers.

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this: we entertain many questions about career development. I realize that this question could get controversial, but there are general principles that are useful to enunciate.

Comment: While we are discussing whether to close this or not, shouldn't we at least CW this?

Comment: @Suresh: My reason to vote to close has nothing to do with the scope.  The question basically asks for anything about evaluating doctoral programs, which is simply too broad a topic to discuss in one question.  In its current form, it is a topic for a blog post, not a question on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela: just flag it :)

Comment: I agree with Peter and Tsuyoshi, I am (virtually) voting to close the question, it is too broad and subjective in its current form. I think OP needs to be more specific about what is important for her/him. Otherwise the general criteria are mainly those listed on [CRA](http://www.cra.org/statistics/nrcstudy2/rankcs.html)'s (outdated) evaluation of PhD programs. Also see Lance Fortnow's related [blog posts](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2007/02/graduate-student-guide.html).

Comment: [Meta-discussion about this question](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/996/186)

Comment: Hi, I guess the post violates some rules in here. I have no idea how remove the post, I did click the delete link but, it seems, it does not allow question with answers. If some of you have privileges please go ahead. Thanks!

Comment: Questions with positive-score answers cannot be deleted for reasons, and I do not think that moderators should delete this question.

Comment: I agree with Tsuyoshi, I would prefer if you edit it to make it less subjective/argumentative. Check [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for some tips about good and bad subjective questions. Try to address the issues raised by commentators here and in the meta discussion.

Comment: @check123, I tried to rephrase your question such that it does not become a ranking question about programs but one about making personal decisions based on experience, feel free to rollback to previous version if you don't like my edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- What are the parameters that one should look for? 
  Number and quality of the faculty working in your area of choice or related areas, ease of finding an advisor, opportunities to collaborate with different people in the program, how well funded the program is, quality of the students, how successful are graduates in finding jobs/positions that you would be interested in after graduating, etc.
- What are credible sources other than institute website/provided materials to get information about the course or program?
  Other students in the program are one of the best sources of information. Most schools should have an Open House for admitted students. Highly recommend you go to them.
- Do brand names really matter? (As in if you had to choose between one with a global and better brand name and other with a strong research focus)
  The story I've heard is that brand names matter in the sense that you'll likely find an excellent and diverse faculty body making it easier to find an advisor and do good work in your field. In addition, on average, the quality of students at such universities is likely to be higher which can be important as at least in my experience, I tend to learn a lot from my peers and work harder if people around me are working hard too.
  You'll also have an easier time getting a good CS job and can also help when looking for a postdoc/faculty position if only because it would be easier to collaborate with a well known faculty member who could write you a great rec.

Answer (score 3):

Addressing the last point, it's stupid to go to a graduate school, no matter how highly ranked it is, if there are no professors there working in your desired area of specialization (assuming you know what it is). One of the most important pieces of graduate school is your advisor. If you know what area you want to work in, either you should make sure there is one professor there in the area you want to work in that you know you are compatible with, or several professors there in the area you want to work in, so you have a choice. If you don't know what area you want to work in, you should go to a school which has a broad enough program that you have a reasonable choice.